# Objective C - URL with ">" string not working

Tags: objective-c, url, uiwebview

I tried to load an url that contains ">" symbol in webview and it gets failed.Provide me with some tips to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Escape* the `>` character using `%3e`.  Here are a [list of characters](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#whatwhy) that should be escaped in URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
NSString *myStr = @"< script >";
[myStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: ... ];
```